# How do you implement if/then logic in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm new to SQL and databases, so bear with me here.

I already know that this query isn't correct, but I think other developers here can understand what I'm trying to do. Any ideas on how to fix this query to get it to work?

```
         SELECT [LabTest], Count(*)
         FROM [UsersDB].[dbo].[vwUserLabTest]
         IF (LabTest='PTT') SET RangeMax=35
         IF (LabTest='CK') SET RangeMax=150
         IF (LabTest='Ca') SET RangeMax=10.1
         WHERE ResultValue>RangeMax
         GROUP By LabTest
```

Comment: look at `CASE WHEN`.

Comment: sounds good i'll look that up and try it out

Comment: I tried CASE WHEN ([LabTest]='PTT') THEN RangeMax=35 but that's throwing up errors too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
SELECT [LabTest], Count(*)
FROM [UsersDB].[dbo].[vwUserLabTest]
WHERE (LabTest = 'PTT' AND ResultValue > 35) OR
      (LabTest = 'CK' AND ResultValue > 150) OR
      (LabTest = 'CA' AND ResultValue > 10.1)
GROUP By LabTest;
```

There are other ways of expressing the logic.  But neither `IF` nor `CASE` are needed -- just simple filtering conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Either of the two following approaches should get you what you're after...

```
SELECT 
    ult.LabTest, 
    LT_Count = COUNT(*)
FROM 
    UsersDB.dbo.vwUserLabTest ult
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (
                        CASE ult.LabTest
                            WHEN 'PTT'  THEN 35.0
                            WHEN 'CK'   THEN 150.0
                            WHEN 'Ca'   THEN 10.1
                        END) 
                        ) rm (RangeMax)
WHERE 
    ult.ResultValue > rm.RangeMax
GROUP By 
    ult.LabTest;
```

-- OR

```
SELECT 
    ult.LabTest, 
    LT_Count = COUNT(*)
FROM 
    UsersDB.dbo.vwUserLabTest ult
WHERE 
    (ult.LabTest = 'PTT' AND ult.ResultValue > 35)
    OR
    (ult.LabTest = 'CK' AND ult.ResultValue > 150)
    OR 
    (ult.LabTest = 'Ca' AND ult.ResultValue > 10.1)
GROUP By 
    ult.LabTest;
```

HTH, Jason

Answer (score 0):

You can use **select in select**
Make **first select** by case when syntax and make **second select** from **first select**.
*For example*

> Block quote

**Select mylabtest, count(*) from(**
Select (case when LabTest = 'PTT' Then 35 else case when LabTest = 'CK' then 150 else LabTest = 'CA' Then 10.1 ) as mylabtest from ....
**) group by mylabtest**

> Block quote

Reguards 
A.Ayati